# Atomic values modification in relaxed order

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

Assume I have the following code snippet:

```
std::atomic<int> a(0);

void thread1()
{
    int x = a.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

void thread2()
{
    int x = a.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(thread1);
    std::thread t2(thread2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

The question is: can I obtain `0 0` as a result?

Here both threads read and modify `a` in a relaxed memory order, so it seems that both of them can see the zero value of `a`. But in practice I see only `0 1` or `1 0`.

Comment: Relaxed ordering is about (lack of) synchronization. Your code has no synchronization problem. Atomic RMW operations still have to be correct even when they are not ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `0 0` is not possible. A relaxed memory order doesn't mean the operations aren't atomic, and the only way for `0 0` to occur is for the read-modify-writes to be non-atomic. But since `std::atomic::fetch_add` operates atomically, we know that only one `fetch_add` may be operating at a time, so only `0 1` or `1 0` are possible.